# What does the operation A'\B' do if A and B are both row vectors of the same size?

Tags: matlab, operation

`[1 2 1]'\[1 2 3]'` This is a numerical example. This example gives an answer of 1.333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html):

```
x = A\B
```

> If `A` is a rectangular `m`-by-`n` matrix with `m ~= n`, and `B` is a matrix with `m` rows, then `A\B` returns a least-squares solution to the system of equations `A*x= B`.

Furthermore the `'` compute the [conjugate transposed](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) of a matrix. In your case you have two real matrices so you just get the transposed each time.

Comment: In other words, your question is the same as `[1; 2; 1]\[1; 2; 3]`.  You can think of this least-squares solution as if it were computed using the pseudoinverse: `A' * inv(A'*A) * B = 1.3333`